# Using Text file of SID's to locate SID's on existing machine

Tags: powershell

I have an user based AD group that performs actions for any system that a user is logged in on. I am working on a script that will locate the User's SID through HKey_Users and store them in a variable. I am trying to take that variable and verify it against the 1387 SID's stored in a text file to see if it is loaded on the PC and perform some action. Right now, I am actually just trying to output a true or false statement. Every response is false. What am I missing?

```
$location = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'

# Get all user SIDs found in HKEY_USERS (ntuser.dat files that are loaded)
$LoadedHives = Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS | ? { $_.PSChildname -match $PatternSID } | Select @{ name = "SID"; expression = { $_.PSChildName } }


$SIDObject = @()  
  foreach ($item in $LoadedHives)
  {
      $props = @{
          SID = $item.SID
      }
      $TempSIDObject = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
      $SIDObject += $TempSIDObject


$SearchString = $TempSIDObject

$UsersSIDS = @{}
foreach ($Line in (Get-Content -Path "$location\LastPassSIDs.txt")) {$UsersSIDS.Add($Line,$true)}
if ($UsersSIDS.$Searchstring) {write-host "True"} Else {Write-host "False"}
$Searchstring
}
```

Every line returns False, yet $Searchstring returns the expected values collected from the registry.

I have tried everything I can think of. A co-worker put me onto the path of the
Hash Array, which I have never used before. The array is filling as expected, although when I view the data with $UsersSIDS, the data is truncated (S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx... True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SantiagoSquarzon, I was able to get this to work as I was wanting to with the following code. The output of the data in your answer had extra characters in it that I could not use when I went to try and delete a key in this user hive.

```
$PatternSID = 'S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+$'
$Users = Get-Childitem Registry::HKEY_USERS | Where-object {
  $name -match $PatternSID
}
 
foreach ($user in $Users) {
  $SID = $user.PSChildName
  Write-Host "My value is" $SID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you're trying to do with your current code but seems awfully complicated, if you want to find all SIDs in `LastPassSIDs.txt` that are in `HKEY_USERS` (`$LoadedHives`) it might be as simple as:

```
$location = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$lastPassSids = Get-Content -Path "$location\LastPassSIDs.txt"

# Get all user SIDs found in HKEY_USERS (ntuser.dat files that are loaded)
$LoadedHives = Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS |
    Where-Object { $_.PSChildname -in $lastPassSids }
```

Comment: This does what I am looking for and is so simple. The End result is that based on the results of the query, I need to delete a registry key. There could be multiple SIDs per machine that will need to have a key removed.

Comment: @Thomas In that case, for deleting the keys it might be better to reverse the filtering so you end up with registry objects, one sec, I'll update my answer